# Is there any alternative of self-signed SSL Certificate?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, openssl, python-3.7, google-colaboratory, sage

I want to solve Quasi Normal Modes (QNM) using [the qnm Python package](https://pypi.org/project/qnm/). I am following Leo Stein's paper (Aug 2019), where he uses the qnm package in the Colab notebook. If I do the same calculation in Jupyter Notebook using SageMath, I get the error below while fetching the URL. I do not understand what the actual issue is. Since SageMath is Python-based and the Colab notebook is also a Jupyter environment, the error is unexpected at this point.

I have OpenSSL 1.1.1 (11 Sep 2018) installed on my Ubuntu 20.04 server. I also tried many times to have the self-signed certificate but I got failed. I am tired now, I need some kind help to remove the error without signing the SSL Certificate (if there is an alternative). I need to know whether the problem is with Sage or Jupyter because the URL can be fetched easily in the Colab notebook using Python.

```
 ?qnm.download_data()
 qnm.download_data()
```

Output:

```
Trying to fetch` https://duetosymmetry.com/files/qnm/data-0.4.0.tar.bz2
data-0.4.0.tar.bz2: 0.00B [00:00, ?B/s]

SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/`home/kamasha/sage/sageinstall/sage-9.1/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)`

     1316                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
    -> 1317                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
      1318             except OSError as err: # timeout error

   SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)

    URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-4-87f2c0b1b969> in <module>()
    
    ----> 1 qnm.download_data()
    
URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate `(_ssl.c:1056)>`
```

I hope this is enough information, I tried my best to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

SSL errors can arise when the Python used by Sage does not have SSL capability.

To check whether this is the case, run this command in Sage:

```
sage: import _ssl
```

If it gives an error, run these commands in the terminal:

```
$ sage -i openssl
$ sage -f python3
```

or if `sage` is not in your path, try this instead:

```
$ cd ~/sage/sageinstall/sage-9.1/
$ ./sage -i openssl
$ ./sage -f python3
```

Next time you build Sage from source, you may want
to install a lot of dependencies system-wide
so that Sage does not have to build them.

One can also [install Sage via Conda](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/conda.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm Leo, the author of the qnm package. Samuel Lelièvre pinged me about this question. In the future I would recommend that bugs be reported to the github issue tracker, https://github.com/duetosymmetry/qnm/issues.

As for the SSL issue: Samuel Lelièvre got it right, I had no problem using `qnm.download_data()` from within `sage`.

However, I have no experience with sage and I did not write the package with sage compatibility in mind. The code does not work there -- because numeric types in sage are not machine ints/doubles/complex types. They are instead objects that carry more information, such as the `sage.rings.integer.Integer` type, `sage.rings.real_mpfr.RealLiteral` type, `sage.rings.complex_number.ComplexNumber`, etc. `numba` is confused when it encounters these types and just gives up.

Since you have sage installed, you can just use the `python3` that comes with it, without all the extras of sage. I would recommend using vanilla python when trying to use `qnm`, unless you know how to get sage to use raw machine numeric types, or you know how to get numba to understand sage types.

Like I said, I don't know anything about sage, so I'm not planning on trying to support it right now. If somebody else knows how to support it and sends me a pull request, I'd gladly take a look!

Best
Leo